# querySelectorAll() exclude attribute and children of that attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a element tree that looks like.

```
<div>
  <div required>
    <div content></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div content></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I do a querySelector on the root div that gets all elements tagged as "content" without getting any that are below a parent element with the "required" attribute? I'm thinking something like.

`querySelectorAll('[content]:not([required]')`

But that query would fetch all elements tagged as content and not tagged as required rather than all elements tagged as content that aren't below a required element.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll(‘div:not([required]) [content]’) should get all elements which have the content attribute which aren’t descendants of an element with the required attribute.

Comment: @BenjaminJamesKippax That won't work, because as long as *any* ancestor lacks the `required` attribute, that ancestor will match, and the child `[content]` will be included.

Comment: @CertainPerformance use the direct descendant selector then? :not([required]) > [content]

Comment: @OP are your `content` elements only ever direct children of a `required` element, or can the `required` be some ancestor?

Comment: @user3875080 Will you check to see if my solution works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `:not` only accepts a simple selector, so `:not([required] [content])` to match a `[content]` which is not a child of `[content]` won't work. You'll have to programmatically filter the elements after selecting them:

```js
const notRequiredContents = [...document.querySelectorAll('[content]')]
  .filter(elm => !elm.closest('[required]'));
console.log(notRequiredContents);
```

```html
<div>
  <div required>
    <div content></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div content></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It'd be theoretically *possible* to do this with only a query string by chaining `:not([required])` with the descendant selector, but it looks really ugly and repetitive and shouldn't be done:

```js
const notRequiredContents = document.querySelectorAll(`
  body > :not([required]) > [content],
  body > :not([required]) > :not([required]) > [content],
  body > :not([required]) > :not([required]) > :not([required]) > [content],
  body > :not([required]) > :not([required]) > :not([required]) > :not([required]) > [content]
`);
// continue above pattern for as much nesting as may exist
console.log(notRequiredContents[0], notRequiredContents.length);
```

```html
<div>
  <div required>
    <div content>a</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div content>b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Repl Example](https://repl.it/repls/CriticalStunningAbility)

**JS**

```
const query = document.querySelectorAll('div :not([required]) [content]')
query.forEach((element) => {
  console.log(element.innerHTML)
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div required>
    <div content>NO</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div content>YES</div>
    <div>
      <div content>YES</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```