# querySelectorAll exclude all children

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using `querySelectorAll` and want to exclude all children of a number of elements. Trying this does not work.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".h:not(.p)").forEach(function(e){
  e.style.color = "red";
});
```

```html
<div class="h">
  Hello World!
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div class="h">
  Hello World!
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div class="h">
  Hello World!
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

How can I achieve only selecting parent elements? Does such a selector exist?

Comment: `.h:not(.p)` selects all elements that have the class `.h` and don't also have the class `.p`

Comment: Why not simply define the red color in CSS and switch the class of the parent element instead? `document.querySelector("#theContainerOfAllDivs").classList.toggle("red");`, `.red .h { color: red; }`.

Comment: Post-filtering might be your only chance here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537626/queryselectorall-exclude-attribute-and-children-of-that-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *is* only selecting the `.h` elements:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".h")
```

But what are you doing with those elements?  You're setting the text color to red:

```
e.style.color = "red";
```

So all text within those elements will be `red`, unless styled otherwise.  If the `.p` elements should be something else, style them as such:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".h").forEach(function(e){
  e.style.color = "red";
});
```

```css
.p {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="h">
  Hello World!
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div class="h">
  Hello World!
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div class="h">
  Hello World!
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Alternatively you might consider re-structuring your HTML.  For example:

```
<div>
  <span class="h">Hello World!</span>
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="h">Hello World!</span>
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="h">Hello World!</span>
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Then you can specifically target the content you want without having to find ways to "exclude" other content.

Comment: Is there not a cleaner way of approaching this?

Comment: @user14773854: "Cleaner" how?

Comment: An existing selector which can do the job?

Comment: @user14773854: The *selector* isn't the problem, the *job* is.  What you're doing is styling all of the `<div>` elements to have red text.  As a result, they all have red text.  I would say that the "cleanest" way to approach this would be to change the markup to be more semantically meaningful and use CSS for the styling instead of JavaScript.

Comment: Modifying the css worked anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you give a parent a color, that will be inherited by the children as well, by default. Your code *is* selecting only the parents, the `.h`s, as you want - the problem is that the children inherit that style as well.

One option is to iterate over the children or descendant `<p>`s as well, and change their colors to what you want, so they don't inherit from the parent.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".h").forEach(function(e){
  e.style.color = "red";
});
document.querySelectorAll(".h .p").forEach(function(e){
  e.style.color = "initial";
});
```

```html
<div class="h">
  Hello World!
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div class="h">
  Hello World!
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div class="h">
  Hello World!
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

A nicer looking option would be to give the text to be colored its own element, and then select those elements only:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".h span").forEach(function(e){
  e.style.color = "red";
});
```

```html
<div class="h">
  <span>Hello World!</span>
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div class="h">
  <span>Hello World!</span>
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div class="h">
  <span>Hello World!</span>
  <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The color is being inherited in the paragraph

```
document.querySelectorAll(".h:not(.p)").forEach(function(e){
  e.style.color = "red";
  e.querySelectorAll(".p").forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.style.color = "black";
  });
});
```